# My pf no on salary slip is MH/PUN/ Can anyone tell me how can I get UAN no if combination for Maharashtra-Pune becomes PU/PUN UAN Member Portal?

Tags: india, retirement, salary, pension, retirement-plan

I work in India, Pune. I want to generate UAN [Universal Account Number] allocated to track the PF [Provident Fund, Govt. Pension scheme].
I was using government site [Employee's Provident Fund Organization, India](http://uanmembers.epfoservices.in/check_uan_status.php)

The PF no. on my previous employer 's salary slip is **MH/PUN/31643/********* . My understanding is first 2 Char MH are for Maharastra State. The next 3 are PUN stand for Pune. However when I check this on the website and used filters Maharastra and Pune, the site shows it in non editable text boxes as *PU/PUN/*

And for no state-region combination, **MH/PUN/** present there, so getting error "Member ID PUPUN0031643 does not exist in member master."

Comment: I'm new here, and if the question is asked in wrong StackExchnage portal, please reply on which portal should I ask this

Comment: I cannot make sense of this question as written because it has too many acronyms. Perhaps this will make more sense to readers in India, but it would be helpful for archival value even if not for getting an answer if someone would write those out.

Comment: @Brick This is very very specific to India. The question makes sense. UAN - Universal Account Number [for Retirement Account under Government Pension Schemes]. PF - Provident Fund. MH- Maharastra State in India. PUN - Pune City in Maharastra State.

Comment: @Dheer I personally think that an edit to the main question with the acronyms written out would improve the question a lot. Even for those out of India who aren't going to understand it, some words would make that clear. I was going to do it, but then I stopped since I might accidentally change the meaning in the event that the acronyms really are better understood than the words.

Answer (score 2):

The new naming convention for Pune Accounts are PU/PUN. All the old accounts should have got rebatched.

Can you re-check if you are entering the correct details. Most organisations help employees get an UAN. Can you check with your Organization if they are able to help you get an UAN.

In your case it could be possible that yours is a very old account and hence not yet updated in the database.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will try to contact my employer(it was a very very small firm who didn't even have accounts dept) But is there any government contact no/mail address where i can query for the same?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade Try uanepf@epfindia.gov.in